# htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my htaccess file.

I have a wordpress site with a page called gallery. I have a lightbox implementation that opens up images and updates the hash of the url. Clicking an image results in this image being opened in the lightbox and the url being updated to:
i.e. hostname/gallery#image-4

Now users should be also able to access the images with the cleaner url structure:
i.e. hostname/gallery/image-4

I figured I should use htaccess to redirect the cleaner url to the hashtag url. But somehow I am not able to get it to work. What would be the right code to use?

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =gallery
RewriteBase hostname/gallery 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ #$1 [R]
```

Comment: Somehow I don't seem to understand the proper behavior of RewriteRule. For example trying out RewriteRule ^gallerys/?$ gallery.php [NC,L] to just redirect when entering hostname/gallerys to hostname/gallery doesn't work. I am pretty lost right now :-S

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your root dir .htaccess, ie, /.htaccess, this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^#]+)$ /gallery#$1 [L]
```